# CAS Proxying not working properly

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security, cas

I have two grails-app (**appA** and **appB**) that are being authenticated/authorized via CAS and Single Sign On is properly functioning.

However, now I have to make **appA** a proxy to **appB** for authentication (**appB** is a web-service and it sends back JSON data). Both apps are communicating via https with CAS and each other.

The PGT and PGTIOU are being generated in CAS and is available in **appB**. However, **appB** is not returning any data to **appA** when fetched via code. So I had some questions:

1. Should single sign on be working between the two apps for proxy to work.
2. Am I supposed to handle the /secure/receptor request in appB by making a SecureController and recptor action.
3. In appA, `proxyCallbackUrl='https://app2.webservice.com:8443/app2/secure/receptor'` and `proxyReceptorUrl = '/secure/receptor'`. Is this correct?
4. In appB, `proxyReceptorUrl = '/secure/receptor'` and there is no `proxyCallBackUrl`, is this correct?
5. My grails version is 1.3.7, the springSecurityCas is 1.0.2, springSecurityCore is 1.1.3 and casServer version =3.4.8
6. If we are supposed to send the *proxyTicket* from **appA** to **appB** as query string while fetching the data from appB, how should we generate the proxy ticket in **appA** or **appB**.

I have been trying to solve this for the last three weeks and failed, so a little help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.